# The best way to draw this branching diagram figure in an equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, equations, tikz-arrows, draw

What is the simple and the best way to draw this figure in an equation?

[image]

Thank you! (tikz is fine.)

(Hopefully, such that $\simeq$ sign in between PDIFF and PL is formulated nicely. My version I shared above the $\simeq$ sign is not very good looking.)

Answer (score 6):

It is not up to me to decide what the "best" way is, but the following is simple IMHO.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[TOP
 [PDIFF
  [DIFF]
  [PL,edge label={node [midway,above,sloped] {$\sim$} } ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you +1, this is one of the best way"s" -- I did not know the "forest"  \usepackage{forest} before!

Comment: @wonderich You're welcome. `forest` is IMHO one of the most amazing Ti*k*Z-based packages that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Here another proposal using `tikz-cd` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{close/.style={outer sep=-7pt}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0cm]
& \text{TOP} \arrow[d, no head] 
&\\
& \text{PDIFF} \arrow[ld, no head] \arrow[rd, close, "{\rotatebox{-40}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\sim$}}}", no head] & \\
\text{DIFF} &   & \text{PL}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you +1, this is one of the best way"s" since I like tikzcd. :-)

Comment: @wonderich Welcome always for me :). I am happy to have help you. My regards.

Answer (score 1):

I draw by this simple way:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node (top) {TOP}
++(-90:1) node (pdiff) {PDIFF}
+(-130:1.5) node (diff) {DIFF}
+(-50:1.5) node (pl) {PL};

\draw (top)--(pdiff)--(diff)
(pdiff)--(pl) node[midway,sloped,above,yscale=.6]{$\sim$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]